# Java JTable set JButton and JTextField but output shows nothing

Tags: java, jtable, jbutton, jtextfield

I have written the following code to make a `JTable`. I am practicing to edit value on row by setting `JButton` and `JTextField` but the output of `JButton` and `JTextField` is unseen.

```
public class quotingtable extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    DefaultTableModel model;
    JTable table;
    String col[] = { "Symbol", "Name", "LastPrice" };
    JButton button = new JButton("Set Value at 1, 1");
    JTextField text = new JTextField(20);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    public void start() {
        model = new DefaultTableModel(col,50);
        table = new JTable(model) {
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int arg0 ,int arg1) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        panel.add(table);
        panel.add(text);
        panel.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String value = text.getText();
                model.setValueAt(value, 1, 0);
            }
        });

        JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setValueAt("VNM", 0, 0);
        add(pane);
        setSize(500, 400);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new quotingtable().start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You add `button`, `text` and `table` to `panel` but you never add `panel` to the frame.

Comment: it works . Thanks alot

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also get used to 
[Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)